# Lucene search on contents of several tags (eXist-db)

Tags: xpath, lucene, xquery, exist-db

I have the following lucene indices in collection.xconf

```
<lucene>
    <text qname="tei:text" />
    <text qname="tei:summary"/>
    <text qname="tei:placeName"/>
</lucene>
```

My xquery code then makes the following query:

```
let $query-results := ($documents[.//tei:text[ft:query(., $q)]],
                    $documents[.//tei:summary[ft:query(., $q)]],
                    $documents[.//tei:placeName[ft:query(., $q)]])
```

Now I want to, say, search on:

```
-pommern erik
```

Now all the documents in query-results have the word "erik" but not the 
word "pommern" in the contents of the tei:text tag.

But some of the results have both "erik" and "pommern" in the 
tei:summary tag.

How do I make an xpath so that the user can search across all three tags 
with lucene syntax (so that the contents of the three tags appears as 
one text)?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are doing a union of the results, you need a intersection instead.

To do this you really need to query against the parent and and the predicates together, something like:

```
$documents[ft:query(.//tei:text, $q)][ft:query(.//tei:summary, $q)][ft:query(.//tei:placeName, $q)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this is too restrictive. The result from this query only returns results with “erik” in both the summary and the text.

What I want is the query to treat the content of the three tags like it was the content of one tag. Something like:

$documents[ft:query(.//tei:text + .//tei:summary + .//tei:placeName, $q)]

Comment: Building on Adam's answer and your reply, try this: `$documents[ft:query(.//tei:text, $q) or ft:query(.//tei:summary, $q) or ft:query(.//tei:placeName, $q)]`

Comment: The or-query above returns 618 results and the one in the question returns 864 results. But both results unfortunately still contains results with the word "pommern" in the summary. We have decided to only search in the contents of the tei:text tag for now (which works), since the other results will confuse the users.